# нужно сделать редирект через button

Tags: javascript, редирект

Есть вот такая кнопка:

```
<button class="layer-send"><span class="layer-footer-action" data-action="send" contenteditable="true">Send</span></button>
```

вот сайт:
https://app.stepform.io/LEB9wFs

Этот код нельзя изменить. Т.е. нельзя добавить id или что-то еще. Но перед ним я могу вставить любой кусок js, html кода.

Мне нужно чтобы после нажатия кнопки layer-send была редирект на другой сайт.

Кто что может подсказать? Спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

... после него:

```
document.querySelector(".layer-send").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location = "другой сайт";
});
```

---

> если его поставить до, он будет работать?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".layer-send").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = "другой сайт";
  });
});
```

Comment: Извините, а если его поставить до, он будет работать?

Comment: @user360794 А зачем? Нет, работать не будет, так как "до" - этого элемента еще нет, и `document.querySelector(".layer-send")` вернет `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.layer-next').forEach(button =>
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.location.href = 'ссылка на другой сайт';
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Не работает. https://app.stepform.io/LEB9wFs вот сайт

Comment: @user360794 отредактировал, попробуйте еще раз

Answer (score 0):

а редирект просто через `<a></a>`?

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com"><button class="layer-send"><span class="layer-footer-action" data-action="send" contenteditable="true">Send</span></button></a>
```